# Reading Hdf5 files with many nodes performance

Tags: python, h5py, pytables

I use hdf5 files in python to save my data to disk to then later read again for further analysis. This dataset consists of about 2000-10000 elements ('cells') which each have 4-6 relatively small numpy arrays (40x80) and a few attributes. The reading of this hdf5 file takes currently several seconds which I'd like to improve.

My current implementation uses `h5py`. I've rewritten the read/write functions in `pytables` but this decreases the performance by a factor of 2. When I use `multiprocessing` together with `h5py` on a 6-core + hyperthreading i7 8700K the speedup is about a factor of 2 for large files.

My current `h5py` implementation is:

```py
def _load_cell(cell_grp):
    data_obj = Data()
    data_grp = cell_grp['data']

    for key in list(data_grp.keys()):
        grp = data_grp[key]
        data_arr = grp[key]
        dclass = grp.attrs.get('dclass').decode('UTF-8')
        data_obj.add_data(data_arr[:], dclass=dclass, name=key)

    c = Cell(data_obj, init_coords=False)

    attr_grp = cell_grp['attributes']
    attr_dict = dict(attr_grp.attrs.items())

    for a in ['r', 'xl', 'xr', 'coeff']:
        setattr(c.coords, a, attr_dict.get(a))
    c.coords.shape = c.data.shape

    name = attr_dict.get('name').decode('UTF-8')
    c.name = name if name is not 'None' else None

    return c

with h5py.File(file_path, 'r') as f:
    cell_list = [_load_cell(f[key]) for key in f.keys()]
```

My `pytables` implementation:

```py
def _load_cell_tables(h5file, key):
    data_obj = Data()

    node = h5file.get_node(key)
    data_grp = node['data']
    for child in data_grp._f_iter_nodes():
        dclass = child._v_attrs['dclass'].decode('UTF-8')
        name = child._v_name

        data_obj.add_data(child[name].read(), dclass=dclass, name=name)

    c = Cell(data_obj, init_coords=False)

    attrs = node.attributes._v_attrs
    for a in ['r', 'xl', 'xr', 'coeff']:
        setattr(c.coords, a, attrs[a])
    c.coords.shape = c.data.shape

    name = attrs['name'].decode('UTF-8')
    c.name = name if name is not 'None' else None

    return c


h5file = open_file(fpath, mode='r')
nodes = h5file.list_nodes('/')
cells = CellList([_load_cell(h5file, node) for node in nodes])
```

`h5py` with `multiprocessing`:

```py
def worker(fpath, key):
    with h5py.File(fpath,  'r', swmr=True) as f:
        cell_grp = f[key]
        return _load_cell(cell_grp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with h5py.File(fpath, 'r') as f:
        keys = list(f.keys())

    pfunk = partial(worker, fpath)
    pool = mp.Pool()
    result = pool.map(pfunk, keys)
```

Is there a way to speed up the reading of these files? From cProfile it looks like most time is spent in the `__getitem__` (h5py) or `get_node` (pytables) functions, since they are being called many times. This does use 100% CPU and the I/O speed of the SSD is not the limiting factor.

For pytables, I've tried setting `driver="H5FD_CORE"` to read the whole file into memory and various value of `NODE_CACHE_SLOTS` (-1, 0, 1,10, 10000) but this doesnt yield any speedup.

I'm wondering if there is a way to increase the reading speed, either other libraries, different read/write implementations or multiprocessing with less overhead.

Comment: Minor cleanup: `list` isn't needed in `for key in data_grp.keys():`

Comment: This might be a case of restructuring your data. Could you describe why you need so many nodes, and why the need to be nested? It seems like you're data is structures as follows:

```
root
   -> cell_group
       -> data_group
            -> arrays
            ...
   ...
```

I can think of a few different ways to structure your file that might help here. If you clarify why you have chosen this structure, I might be able to post a helpful answer.

Comment: This is because of the hierarchy of my data. Each of the cells has a few arrays associated with it. On top of that each cell has 6 attributes and every array has another attribute. I've considered merging all arrays together into one big array, however, they all have slightly different shapes and dtypes